# Jupyter - Python 3 kernel dies

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Fedora 21, default Python is 2.7, 3.x installed, originally installed iPython,  now have also installed Jupyter

When I try to use the Python3 kernel from Jupyter notebook, I get a message saying the kernel has died, attempting restart.  Naturally restart never succeeds.

Tried following these 2 terminal commands

ipython kernelspec install-self

ipython3 kernelspec install-self

first command executes without error.  second gives this error
ipython3 kernelspec install-self

I used iPython with Python 3 kernel in the past, before installing Jupyter.  I don't remember installing ipython3 to do so.

Suggestions how to resolve?  I have searched and the above was the only suggestion I found that was not based on using Anaconda.

Also, I do have kernel.json at
~/.ipython/kernels/python3

thank you

UPDATE
last output on terminal when kernel dies

ImportError: No module named 'ptyprocess'

UPDATE2 traceback error

```
[xxxxx@localhost ~]$ sudo ipython3 kernelspec install-self
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ipython3", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 24, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 116, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ptyprocess
ImportError: No module named 'ptyprocess'
```

UPDATE3:
after installing ptyprocess with pip3 new error when trying to create notebook with Python 3...No module named 'path'

```
[I 22:29:26.125 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 1ae58a7d-096b-4dc1-b29a-bee4385e4e9a restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pickleshare import PickleShareDB
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pickleshare.py", line 41, in <module>
    from path import path as Path
ImportError: No module named 'path'
[W 22:29:29.137 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install ptyprocess`

Comment: @MeshachBlue  i did but i forgot to try `pip3 install ptyprocess`  Now new error "No module named 'path'".  See above for full traceback

Answer (score 0):

I've just been installing python, ipython, upyter and pyspark as a kernel. I run into some troubles that seem to be close to what you are having. Many times that I used "sudo ..." I would get the wrong python version. I think somehow sudo run commands without a shell, so if you have any configuration (path, python version,etc), you may not get it applied when using sudo. Something you could do is to run "sudo python", then see if you can import the module path. Also you could try to run "sudo which python" to make sure it's the right version. I found that even if the user had python 2.7 installed, sudo would use python 2.6. For me the best thing to do was to log in as root and do the installation without sudo...

Comment: I ended up doing a clean install in a vm with xubuntu guest os and installed anaconda.  When I do a  clean install of F23 after release I will battle this again but I think it will go better because it will be a Jupyter install, not upgrade from ipython

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning python with the jupyter notebook, and I came across the same problem you did.  An associate found the problem - I had crated a python program random.py and saved it into my Python directory.  Since random is also the name of a module that I installed, an error message was generated in the Anaconda prompt window.  Please check your directories for .py files named after reserved words and modules.